# Switching to websocket from simple Berkeley socket

Tags: sockets, websocket

I have a simple socket implementation which uses the standard low-level [Berkeley socket functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) (bind, listen, accept, read, etc).

This socket listens on a port, let's say X.

Now what I'm trying to achieve is to make [Simple-WebSocket-Server](https://gitlab.com/eidheim/Simple-WebSocket-Server) to listen also on this port X.

**Of course this is not possible by nature - I know.**

**My intention is this:** In my simple socket implementation I would detect if the connected client (after accepting) is my client or a websocket one, then if I find the client to be a websocket one, I would pass the whole thing into this library to behave the same as like it was the one have accepted this client.

What would be good to hand over the socket's fd, along with a first bytes that my socket read before noticing a websocket request.

I'm a bit stuck on would be the best to do this, but I don't want to reimplement the whole websocket stuff for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky thing here is that the Simple-WebSocket-Server does its own `accept`, so I don't there is a way to had over to it a `fd` together with an array of "first bytes".

Some approaches I could think of:

- modify the Simple-WebSocket-Server so that instead of closing a non-WS client or timing-out, it makes a call to your library
- instead use something like [websocketpp](https://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp) to create your own websocket server, and then select between the two servers (I did something similar for one of my own projects, where I had to detect the socket protocol from the first byte and then select an appropriate protocol handler [wampcc protcol selector](https://github.com/darrenjs/wampcc/blob/master/libs/wampcc/protocol.cc#L201))
- or, you could try to have the Simple-WebSocket-Server listen on a different port Y; you also listen on X, and if detect a web-socket client on X, you internally create an internal pair of queues and then open a connection to `localhost:Y`, and proceed to transfer bytes between the pair of sockets; this way you don't need to modify the Simple-WebSocket-Server code.

Comment: I would prefer a method where my basic Berkeley socket can be 'the master', so method 3 would be okay, but I would also like to not bring more overhead into the picture than what is exactly needed.